# Changing the boundaries in this double integral problem.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I am going to attempt this but with the following modification to the boundaries:

$$x=0\quad to\quad x=sin^{-1}y\\
y=0\quad to\quad y=1\\m=\int_0^1\int_0^{sin^{-1}y}ydxdy\\=\int_0^1ysin^{-1}ydy\\=\pi/8$$

I computed the inner integral assuming y is constant. It seems like I am not getting the same answer. Any reason why?

Comment: The problem is that when you use horizontal slices, there are two regions to consider, i.e. from $y=0$ to $y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ the rightmost bounding curve is $cos^{-1}{y}$.

Comment: @Doc: Ah, so you have to split the integral into two parts: one where the bound is $x=cos^{-1}y$ and another where $x=sin^{-1}y$, right?

Comment: Now you got it!